# adding custom tags in playlist in jwplayer6

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I need to add some custom tags for the videos in a playlist which is later used during the playback of the video. I created a simple playlist and looks like

```
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">
    <pl>
       <item>
           <title>testtitle</title>
           <description>testdesc</description>
           <jwplayer:source file="somefileaddress" />
           <jwplayer:level1>
                 <jwplayer:level2>level2text</jwplayer:level2>
                 <jwplayer:level3>level3text</jwplayer:level3>
           </jwplayer:level1>
          </item>
     </pl>
     </rss>
```

Parts of JWplayer call:

```
    jwplayer('div').setup({
            playlist: 'pl.rss',
        });
        jwplayer().onReady(function (event) {
             var item = jwplayer().getPlaylistItem('1');
             alert(item.level1); 
        })
```

I get an alert with all the text inside the tags of **jwplayer:level1** excluding any tags.

Is there a way we can get hold of texts inside tags **jwplayer:level2** and **jwplayer:level3**

Comment: I'm afraid the player doesn't really know what to do with those tags, so I don't believe this is possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Another optimization query. I have a huge playlist file which runs for whole 24 hours and each item has lots of new tags which I declared myself and not nested. During the play time, I decide which tag to use so all the tags are important. 

Which one is more efficient and optimised
1) have everything dumped into one file or
2) use another xml file where I declare all the new tags and relate it with the playlist file from the code.

I am worried about memory optimization here. Can you help?

Comment: Hm, do you have an example of where you are running this?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Not yet. I am about to start working on it but I was worried about memory usage and delay that might happen for both the option (long playlist or additional files). Is there anywhere I can read about the causes of delay and best option to follow with memory optimization for jwplayer. I have not found any during my research. Would appreciate any kind of help. Tx

Comment: We don't really have any documentation on this subject, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @EthanJWPlayer Will then test with both and notify you how it goes.

Comment: Np, please let me know.